# Installing GeoMesa Cassandra in GeoServer

Tags: maven, ubuntu, cassandra, geoserver, geomesa

i recently started working with geomeas and cassandra database, i started using this quickstart guide: https://www.geomesa.org/documentation/tutorials/geomesa-quickstart-cassandra.html
in the visualize using geoserver section, for installing geomesa in cassandra, i downloaded the plugin and extracted the files in the required directory, but still cant see the cassandra geomesa vector datasource in the geoserver..

Comment: What version of GeoMesa, GeoServer and Cassandra are you using? Did you install the Cassandra jars into GeoServer after extracting the geomesa-plugin files (e.g. using `bin/install-cassandra-jars.sh`)?

Comment: GeoMesa:2.1.0, Cassandra:3.11.3, GeoServer: 2.14.0,

Comment: yes i  installed the cassandra jars in the geoserver lib directory as mentioned in the tutorial, and i can see the jars installed successfully with the correct versions

Comment: @EmilioLahr-Vivaz..

Answer (score 1):

GeoMesa currently targets GeoServer 2.12.x, try using that version.

Comment: i just tried the same thing with Geoserver 2.12.5, still doesnt work,
i think the part causing this is "extract the archive and copy the contents to the WEB-INF/lib", i took the bin, conf, lib..  plugin folders and pasted them in the WEB-INF/lib directory of the GeoServer, am i doint it right ? @EmilioLahr-Vivaz

Comment: Generally you just untar geomesa-cassandra-gs-plugin_2.11-*-install.tar.gz into WEB-INF/lib, then run `bin/install-cassandra-jars.sh /path/to/WEB-INF/lib`. But seems like you got it working?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is solved after i copied only the jars inside the lib folder of the plugin and paste them with the jars of the Geoserver in the WEB-INT/lib directory